# Is it possible to implicitly assign attributes to a class, from an inherited class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have been unable to find any questions on this or maybe I am using the wrong nomenclature in my search.  If I have something like:

```
class testone(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attone = None
        self.atttwo = None
        self.attthree = None

class testtwo(testone):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attfour = None
```

And I do:

```
a = test()
print dir(a)

b = testtwo()
print dir(b)
```

One can see that `a` will have all of it's attributes defined as `None`  but `b` will only have `attfour` defined even though it inherited class `testone`.  I understand this, but is it possible to make `b` have all of the attributes inherited from `a` implicitly defined as well at instantiation ?

I ask b/c I have classes that have tens of attributes that are inheriting from classes with hundreds of attributes and I need every attribute to be defined even if it is of type `None` so that I don't have to worry about checking if the attribute exists before mapping it from my object to a database table.  I am trying not to write as much code.  If there is a way to do this then I save well over a thousand lines of code in my class definitions or I could just verify if each attribute exists before mapping the object to my table but that's a lot of code as well as I have a couple thousand attributes to check.

Comment: You replaced the `__init__` method in the subclass; you want to call the *overridden* version. `super().__init__()` can do that (Python 3), or `super(testtwo, self).__init__()` (both Python 2 and 3).

Comment: @MartijnPieters not sure how this is a duplicate of that question but oh well. My question does not ask how to "Call a parent class's method" or attribute. My question asks about having all of a parent classes attributes implicitly defined at instantiation of a child class.  Also that questioner is already aware of the super solution. I was unaware of super() as it is only mentioned once in the [class inheritance doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and then only when discussing multiple inheritance, which my question had nothing to do with.

Comment: You'll need to call the parent `__init__` method. I read this as '*how* do I call a parent `__init__` method, rather than '*should* I call the parent `__init__` method?', to which the answer is: "yes, because that method sets those attributes, nothing else".

Comment: this is why i wrote "maybe I am using the wrong nomenclature in my search".  i know what i want but can't put it into words.  It hadn't dawned on me that the solution i needed was to call the __init__ method on the parent class.  Saying it that way, it does make sense that its a duplicate.  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but since you have overridden `__init__` in the derived class, you will have to explicitly init the next class in the mro (a parent or sibling class).

```
class testone(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attone = None
        self.atttwo = None
        self.attthree = None

class testtwo(testone):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attfour = None
        super(testtwo, self).__init__()  # on python3 just use super()
```

For more details on inheritance, read the docs on [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

*Note:* I assumed you have meant for `testtwo` to inherit `testone` in your question, and have made that correction.

Comment: yes you are right, I did intend to inherit 'testone'.  I just corrected it.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  I read the python docs on [class inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) before asking this but there was no explanation of this and the only mention of super() concerned cases of multiple inheritance so I did not click on super() and read its docs,  where it goes on to explain the solution to my situation perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you overrode `testone.__init__` you will have to call the `super()` function in `testtwo`.  Another thing you can do is take the `__init__` variables

```
class testone(object):
    attone = None
    atttwo = None
    attthree = None

class testtwo(testone):
    attfour = None
```